# Do Airbus aircraft fitted with ACT have additional fuel system controls?

Tags: cockpit, airbus, fuel-systems, aircraft-operations

Do Airbus aircraft fitted with ACT (Additional Center Tank) have a push button that controls the fuel transfer to the main center tank? If yes, where is it located?

Answer (score 3):

[image]
(Source: Airbus)

Yes they do on the same overhead fuel panel. The additional pb is shown above. If it is not pushed and no fault is shown, then it is in automatic operation, and pushing it allows manual fuel transfer.

Comment: thank you very much! I spent quite enough time when was looking it on A320 overhead Fuel panel). It was added just on A321
PS: Thank you for editing my post. I have to admit my English still needs improvement